# Docker for Windows auto startup

Tags: docker

I've installed Dockers for Windows. Every time I start my computer it does not start up properly. I am always faced with this dialog.

[image]

I've tried starting and stopping the service, but it never seems to startup properly upon windows startup.

Comment: do you have your virtualization enabled? which windows version you use? is it the home version or another version

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that in my description. I have Windows 10 Professional. It's usually up to date. It ran the updater today, but it was still doing it after the update. I'm not sure what you mean about virtualization enabled?

Comment: that is something that you need to enable using your BIOS settings since it is disabled by default in order to use docker. for more information refer to this link https://mashtips.com/enable-virtualization-windows-10/

Comment: OK, I do have virtualization enabled.